# inserting millions of documents - mongo / pymongo - insert_many

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

New to mongo/pymongo.
Currently using the latest - v3.2.2

It looks as if insert_many is not performing as intended?  I've noticed that even when supplying a generator to db.col.insert_many, memory usage still spikes (which makes inserting millions of documents difficult - though I do realize that sys.mem should be > collection size for best performance, so in reality perhaps this is nothing I should worry about?

I was under the impression that if you pass a generator to insert_many that pymongo will 'buffer' the insert into 16 or 32mb 'chunks'?

Performing this buffering/chunking manually solves the issue...

See below:

Example1 = straight insert_many (high memory usage - 2.625 GB)

Example2 = 'buffered' insert_many (expected [low] memory usage - ~300 MB)

```
import itertools
from itertools import chain,islice
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient()
db=client['test']

def generate_kv(N):
    for i in range(N):
        yield {'x': i}

print "example 1"
db.testcol.drop()
db.testcol.insert_many(generate_kv(5000000))

def chunks(iterable, size=10000):
        iterator = iter(iterable)
        for first in iterator:
            yield chain([first], islice(iterator, size - 1))

print "example 2"
db.testcol.drop()
for c in chunks(generate_kv(5000000)):
        db.testcol.insert_many(c)
```

Any ideas?  Bug? Am I using this wrong?

Comment: if you are making this test on same system where mongo and python is installed - you are asking for trouble :-). 1. python need to allocate memory for created object, 2. tcp/ip stack need to transfer that, 3. mongo need to buffer input.... so looks like one object can be allocated three times..

Comment: absolutely.  For this test I am indeed using the same system for mongo/python (simple VM in virtualbox).  In reality mongoDB would be running in it's own environment with plenty of memory.  My post was only referencing the memory usage of the python loading (pymongo) script, not the entire systems mem usage.

Answer (score 4):

I think that happens because for `insert_many` pymongo need to have a complete `list` of operations, not `iterable`. After this list will be sent to MongoDB and after that, it will be processing.

- If you want/need to use iterable (e.g. long document generation) - you can use simple `insert`.
- If you have a big amount of documents that fit your RAM - you can send bulk insert (`insert_many`).
- In other cases - just split by biggest chunks that you can and send to MongoDB.

This is normal behavior for databases.